# Searching for posts without a tag borks the search parameters

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-search

Currently, search seems to be doing odd things when you search for posts without certain tag(s) using the not operator. For example:

`-[css] -[html]` should return a list of posts that do not have the CSS or HTML tags, and it correctly looks for that criteria. However, it also seems to *change* my search query to `"-[css] -[html]"` (note the quotation marks) and searches for posts  which do not have the CSS and HTML tags, but also contain the words CSS and HTML within them.

> [image: Search is Borken]

The same thing happens whether you search for one or many tags. This doesn't seem to happen if you don't use the not operator on the tags.

Comment: Well, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-javascript) works at least.

Comment: I blame the new nav.

Comment: This looks like quite a serious bug (search is vital part of SE) can't you use  your power to bump it internally? :)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem when searching for tags with **-** operator (used for 'exclude' tags). But when I add an extra option say for e.g. "is:question" it works perfectly fine.

Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

Even the single tag search e.g. `-[css]` gets converted to "-[css]". Could it be because of the "-" modifier?. It seems that way as my search for [css] works perfectly but as soon as I prefix with **-** operator it treats as a special char. and surrounds with quotes.

Another thing I noticed is that it works perfectly when you search an exclude tag with an include tag e.g. a combination of either `[css] -[html]` or `-[css] [html]`.

Here is the screenshot of the combination:

> [image]

But the moment you add ***two*** (or multiple) tags with **-** operator e.g. `-[css] -[html]` it puts quotation marks around the search query. Does it means we can't *just* search with an excluded tags? I am confused on how to interpret this behavior.

Comment: It seems to be doing this only when all the given search terms are negated tags. Corrects itself whenever something else is thrown into the mix, whatever it might be.

Comment: @animuson that's what I found too. I have added P.S. in my answer on the same but even -[css] gets converted to "-[css]"